# "oldValue" and "newValue" default parameters names inside willSet / didSet unrecognized

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am currently writing Swift 3 code in Xcode 8.

When using `oldValue` and `newValue` default parameters inside the `willSet` and `didSet` blocks, I am getting `"unresolved identifier"` compiler error.

I have a very basic code as below

```
var vc:UIViewController? {
    willSet {
        print("Old value is \(oldValue)")
    }
    didSet(viewController) {
        print("New value is \(newValue)")
    }
}
```

[Apple Documentation](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj7n9XolJnPAhWFGpQKHeXXANQQ0gIIJSgCMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fcontent%2Fdocumentation%2FSwift%2FConceptual%2FSwift_Programming_Language%2FProperties.html%23%2F%2Fapple_ref%2Fdoc%2Fuid%2FTP40014097-CH14-ID262&usg=AFQjCNFIMhNRyqKTM-jorsBH6wVdpj1NtA&sig2=EV_0ZFWLWuitpplTfkOl2Q) for Swift 3 still seems to support these feature. 
I hope I am not missing anything here?

Answer (score 94):

You can also use `vc`:

```
var vc:UIViewController? {
    willSet {
        print("New value is \(newValue) and old is \(vc)")
    }
    didSet {
        print("Old value is \(oldValue) and new is \(vc)")
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the current Swift version of this?

Answer (score 72):

The special variable `newValue` only works within `willSet`, while `oldValue` only works within `didSet`.

The property as referenced by its name (in this example `vc`) is still bound to the old value within `willSet` and is bound to the new value within `didSet`.

Answer (score 25):

```
var vc:UIViewController? {
    willSet {
        print("New value is \(newValue)")
    }
    didSet {
        print("Old value is \(oldValue)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Not entirely right, oldValue still seems to be unrecognized. Removing `viewController` parameter seems to make it work.

Comment: From your answer, I was able to deduce that `newValue` works within `willSet` and `oldValue` works for `didSet` block given there are no custom parameters.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I did not notice ur variable.

Comment: Incidentally, https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html documents the default parameter names of `newValue` and `oldValue` for the `willSet` and `didSet` property observers, respectively.

Answer (score 17):

It's important to know that the special variable `newValue` only works within `willSet`, while `oldValue` only works within `didSet`.

```
var vc: UIViewController? {
    willSet {
        // Here you can use vc as the old value since it's not changed yet
        print("New value is \(newValue)")
    }
    didSet {
        // Here you can use vc as the new value since it's already DID set
        print("Old value is \(oldValue)") 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't try to initialize the variable with a new object by which you can set your clojure:

```
var vc:UIViewController? = UIViewController(){
   willSet { 
       print("Old value is \(oldValue)")
   }
   didSet(viewController) {
       print("New value is \(newValue)")
   }
}
```

Answer (score -7):

That's why we use NSKeyValueObservation to monitor class object